# Sencha Touch form fields show gap

Tags: sencha-touch, formpanel

I am using following code to create a form in my application.

```
var startAddressPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    title: 'Address',
    fullscreen: true,
    scroll: 'vertical',
    id: 'start_address',
    defaults: {
        labelWidth: '30%'
    },
    items: [txtFromStreet, 
            txtFromCity, 
            selFromProvince, 
            txtFromPostalCode, 
            selFromCountry]
    });
```

In the resultant form each field has a small gap underneath. 
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the labelWidth percentage until the gap no longer exists.